# How can I extract a key from an SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, rsa, pki, pem

I have an SSL certificate I purchased in a `.pem`, `.crt`, `.der` format. I was wondering how I get the key file from the certificate. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Are you talking of the *private* key?

Comment: Why? You already have both the private and the public key. That's where you started. You generated a key pair, created a CSR, got it signed, now you have the signed certificate. If you've lost the key pair you started with, you are hosed anyway, you have to start again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can extract the public key. This has limited usefulness. Perhaps you are going to use the same key with another tool like SSH or PGP that doesn't use certificates.

With OpenSSL:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout < cert.pem > pubkey.pem
```

You can't derive the private key from a certificate. That would make the whole thing quite pointless, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm getting an error when running the command:

`openssl rsa -pubout <cert.pem > key.pem`
`
unable to load Private Key
99416:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
`

Comment: @nkcmr I apologize. I thought I was testing the command on a certificate, but it was actually a file I made for `s_server` to use. In this format, the private key is appended to the certificate, and the presence of that private key allows the `rsa` utility to work. Please use my corrected answer.