# How to sign XML using xmlsec and CSP?

Tags: c++, cryptoapi, xmlsec

I need to sign XML using xmlsec and certificate provided by csp. (C++, Linux only)
Here is the simplified code.

```
HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
hStore = CertOpenStore();
PCCERT_CONTEXT pContext = CertFindCertificateInStore(hStore...);
//xml preparation using libxml2

xmlSecKeyPtr signKey = xmlSecKeyCreate();
xmlSecDSigCtxPtr dsigCtx = xmlSecDSigCtxCreate(mngr);
dsigCtx->signKey = ???; // How to set sign key?
xmlSecDSigCtxSign(dsigCtx, signNode);
```

How to set signkey? How to extract it from cert?
In Java it's done by CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey with cryptSetProvParam setting password. But in Linux no success with this call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [documentation](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/)? Try these two links:

https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/xmlsec-verify-with-key.html

https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/xmlsec-notes-sign.html

Specifically, this line looks like it sets the sign key, with key_file being a char array:

```
dsigCtx->signKey = xmlSecCryptoAppKeyLoad(key_file, xmlSecKeyDataFormatPem, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This should help getting the key from a cert:
[How can I extract a key from an SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560006/how-can-i-extract-a-key-from-an-ssl-certificate)

Comment: The problem is that i DON'T have key_file. What I have is PCCERT_CONTEXT provided by CSP.